# Batch transliterate Excel XLSX files

Tags: microsoft-excel, language

I've got about 10 thousand XLSX files that have content in Cyrillic alphabet. I need to [transliterate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) the content of these files into Latin alphabet.

Is there any way to do it with Excel or do I have any other options?

Comment: I was so sure that "transliterate" wasn't a word! Learn something new every day.

Comment: Your question was off topic, we're not here to just provide you with source code etc. I've edited your question, if you want to roll it back, feel free. Either way, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) to so far?

Comment: At least you should provide a conversion Excel table where all cyrillic letters have there latin counterpart at the same row. Most of us have no clue if [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian) is complete and enough for you

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it would stand performance-wise, but it can be done to a certain degree with user-defined VBA function, taking the Cyrillic string as argument, iterating through all the characters and replacing each of the Cyrillic letter with the translitterated equivalent, and returning the result.

A quick google search showed me https://gist.github.com/jenikm/3020221 which does the exact reverse of your task, I am sure you could find even more useful material.